# Static variables initialization order

Tags: c#

I have put breakpoint into "get"

```
static readonly LawClass s_Law = new LawClass();
public static LawClass Law { get { return s_Law; } }
```

and found out s_law is null.

How is it possible? I thought static variables are initialized before first class access and in line-by-line order.

Comment: unlikely to be actual answer, but there could be a static constructor that sets it back to null (i.e. a developer was just being mean).  Also, in the future could you please provide code snippets as text, not as pictures of text?

Comment: Why not check `s_Law` in the getter and set it to a new instance if it is null?

Comment: @mgnoonan Well, it's `readonly`, so you couldn't set it if you tried.  Beyond that; the point is that it should never be null because it's initialized to a value and can't be changed afterwards.

Comment: Is there an error being thrown in the LawClass constructor?

Comment: @Servy True, I guess I am wondering if it needs to be readonly internally, or if just having a readonly getter is sufficient. In either case, I agree the code as displayed should work.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Only thing I can think of is that there is an unshown [ThreadStatic] attribute above the readonly field, and that the instance is created from one thread, and the get is called from another thread. Static initializations are only done once.

Comment: Is `null` actually being returned?

Comment: This is likely a debugger artefact.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a guess, but from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If a static constructor (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution
>   of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing
>   that static constructor. **Otherwise, the static field initializers are
>   executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of
>   a static field of that class**.

If you break on the property getter, the static backing field hasn't been accessed yet, and therefore might or might not have been initialized.

Comment: Where you have currently broken, the line of code requiring the defined value of s_Law isn't yet needed. On the next line, a value will be required and I would expect the initialization to occur at that time. Statics aren't required to be lazy, but in the Microsoft CLR they usually are.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for help! I looked at stack trace and found out I had some crazy recursion in my static variables initialization order. So I simplified the code and now it works.